# IUPAC naming of alkyl halide

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why is

> 4-Bromopent-2-ene

correct but

> 2-Bromopent-3-ene

not correct by IUPAC nomenclature? I don't see anything wrong in the second case.
Which rule does it violate?

Note that I am naming the same compound by the above mntioned names.

Answer (score 1):

Which rule does it violate? E.g. P-15.1.7.2.3 (from section Types of Nomenclature – Substitutive nomenclature), which might not fit perfectly for our example, but it refers to much more detailed P-14.4 rule.

> P-15.1.7.2.3
>
> When several nomenclatural features are present in a structure,
>   lowest locants are assigned in accordance With P-14.4. For example,
>   in a cyclic unsaturated alcohol having one substituent group,
>   lowest locants are assigned in the order:
>   (a) characteristic group cited as suffix (-ol);
>   (b) unsaturation (‘ene’ ending, for example);
>   (c) detachable alphabetized prefxes (a methyl group, for instance).

Bromo substituent is considered detachable prefix, not a characteristic group, so only b) and c) rules do apply.

Therefore,
$\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CH(Br)-CH3}$ is 4-bromopent-2-ene
but
$\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CH(OH)-CH3}$ is pent-3-en-2-ol.